# CRS invalid projection

Tags: python, geopandas

When I try this function, I get an error.

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = "Coordinates", crs=4326)
```

---

> CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name)

It worked fine last time, but when I tried running today, it gave me this error.
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `crs="EPSG:4326"`.

Answer (score 4):

Your installation of `pyproj` does not see the correct database. See https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select.

This often happens if you start Jupyter in one environment and change the kernel. The link to PROJ database remains the same which may cause troubles.

For example, let's assume that I have started Jupyter lab in `geo_env` environment and then switched kernel to `development` environment and got the error as you did.

I can check my proj dictionary:

```
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.datadir.get_data_dir()
'/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/share/proj'
```

See that it still links to the env I started Jupyter with. I can fix that by specifying the correct path.

```
>>> pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir('/opt/miniconda3/envs/development/share/proj')
```

The situation is analogous in any other case when you see this error. You just have to specify the correct path to `proj`.

Comment: This seems to be the solution. But where should the the pyproj directory be located?

Comment: `sys.prefix()` + `share/proj` should normally work but check that before.

Comment: I think it should be 'sys.prefix() + "/share/proj"'. However, I cannot see the proj folder in my share directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: I solved the above comment by installing `conda install -c conda-forge proj-data`. However, if I `set_data_dir()` in jupyter, it does not persist ad changes back

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem for a couple of days.  The problem comes from the library Pyproj.  The following points solved my problem:

1. Create a total new conda enviroment:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create -n pyproj_env pyproj
conda activate pyproj_env
```

2. Create a new project using this new enviroment
3. Install geopandas using conda

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue creating a environment.yml file where I include all the packages required and then create the environment based on it.

- environment.yml

> name: geo_env
>
> channels:
>
> - conda-forge
>
> dependencies:
>
> - numpy
> - scipy
> - pandas
> - scikit-learn==1.1.1
> - geopandas
> - pickle5
> - matplotlib
> - seaborn
> - libpysal
> - osmnx
> - contextily
> - tobler

- Create environment

> ```
> $ cd <your folder name>
> $ conda env create -f environment.yml
> ```