# Error reading spatial files in Python "Invalid projection: EPSG:4326"

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas, pyproj

Im having problems reading any kind of spatial file in Python (such as GeoJson or Shapefile) the error that I get is the following:

`CRSError: Invalid projection: EPSG:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name)`

I have tried to install different versions of pyproj and geopandas but  nothing makes any different, I have no idea where this error come from.

Comment: Related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383883/pyproj-invalid-projection-init-epsg25832

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CRS invalid projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66156417/crs-invalid-projection)

Comment: I have not found a solution